# Stock with slow SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been working with the same SQL query for a couple of hours and it is finally working. But, it is very slow.. I have been trying to optimize it, but no luck, any help. Here is the query (Lots of left joins...):

```
 $sql ="SELECT u.id, u.display_name, IFNULL(SUM(r.total_rating)/COUNT(r.total_rating), 0) AS avg_rating, s.title AS study FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN rating r ON u.id = r.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta m ON u.id = m.user_id
  LEFT JOIN usermeta m1 ON u.id = m1.user_id
  LEFT JOIN studies s ON m.meta_value = s.id
  WHERE m.meta_key = 'study' AND m1.meta_key = 'subjects' AND m1.meta_value REGEXP '$subjectsvalues'
  GROUP BY u.id, r.total_rating
  ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
  LIMIT 10";
```

Table structure for user table:

```
id | display_name | email
-------------------------
 1 | Khar         | ...
 2 | SantaCruz    | ...
```

Table structure for rating table:

```
id | rating_title | total_rating  | user_id
-------------------------------------------
 1 | dffd         | 5             | 1
 2 | fddfdffdd    | 4             | 1
```

Table structure for usermeta table:

```
id | user_id | meta_key  | meta_value
-------------------------------------
 1 | 1       | study     | 132
 2 | 1       | subjects  | 121,231
```

Table structure for studies table:

```
id | title
----------
 1 | dsdsf
 2 | sdfdf
```

Subject values are handled like so:

```
$subjectsvalues = '';

$subjects = explode(",", $subjects);
foreach($subjects as $val) {
    $subjectsvalues = $subjectsvalues.",".$val.",|";
}
$subjectsvalues = $subjectsvalues."notdata";
```

Comment: That's a lot of left joins.  Please edit your question to include the table structure of your tables as well as what your expected results are.

Comment: Hi @JenR, i have updated the post, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the query results are OK? You are grouping by `r.total_rating` and calculate `SUM` and `COUNT` agreggates on the same column.  I think the grouping should be on `u.id, u.display_name, s.title`

Answer (score 0):

First, `left join`s are unnecessary.  So try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.display_name, AVG(r.total_rating) AS avg_rating, s.title AS study
FROM users u JOIN
     rating r
     ON u.id = r.user_id JOIN
     usermeta m
     ON u.id = m.user_id JOIN
     usermeta m1 
     ON u.id = m1.user_id JOIN
     studies s
     ON m.meta_value = s.id
WHERE m.meta_key = 'study' AND m1.meta_key = 'subjects' AND m1.meta_value REGEXP '$subjectsvalues'
GROUP BY u.id, r.total_rating
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Then, I would be inclined to try indexes on `usermeta(meta_key, user_id, meta_value)`.  I assume the main ids in the tables are all primary keys.

Comment: Okay, I see. I will give it a shot, thanks a bunch! Btw, I have updated the post to include the table structure.

Comment: Hi Gordon, i have updated the post to include table structure and the $subjectvalues variable. How would i go about indexing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest an edit to Gordon Linoff's answer, so here's an improved version. You don't really need to `join` with `usermeta` twice unless `usermeta` is being compared with itself.

```
SELECT u.id, u.display_name, AVG(r.total_rating) AS avg_rating, s.title AS study
FROM users u JOIN
     rating r
     ON u.id = r.user_id JOIN
     usermeta m
     ON u.id = m.user_id JOIN
     studies s
     ON m.meta_value = s.id
WHERE m.meta_key = 'study' OR (m.meta_key = 'subjects' AND m.meta_value REGEXP '$subjectsvalues')
GROUP BY u.id, r.total_rating
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Also, could you please explain the utility of your regular expression? It most likely won't match anything as `$` indicating end of the pattern is placed at start of regex.

Comment: Thank for your answer! Very helpfull, $subjectsvalues is a variable containing the subject ids we are searching for. Eg. ,142,213.

Comment: You should add the [tag:PHP] tag to the question.

Comment: Hi! I tried your code, but it seems to break somewhere, it only returns 13 users of a 509 total on with matching criterias. I have updated the post with $subjectvalues.

Comment: @MikkelEmilLindblom It would be helpful if you put in words what you're trying to achieve with your query.